# aws application load balancer finding the automatically generating a listener

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I'm using aws_cdk aws_elasticloadbalancingv2 to generate application load balancer.  When this generates it creates a public listener on its own for port 80.  How do I find the listener arn using cdk python?  I don't know the listener arn. I only have the load balancer that I created arn.  Should I be able to change this listener to be a redirect action instead of forward action?

Answer (score 1):

The python's `ApplicationListener` class in CDK has [listener_arn](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_elasticloadbalancingv2/ApplicationListener.html#aws_cdk.aws_elasticloadbalancingv2.ApplicationListener.listener_arn) property.

Thus if you create a listern, you can use that property. For example:

```
listener = lb.add_listener("Listener", port=80)
arn = listener.listener_arn
```

Full example is [here](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-cdk-examples/blob/master/python/application-load-balancer/app.py).

Comment: If the creation of the load balancer automatically creates  a public listener on port 80, is there a way to find what listeners are attached to a load balancer using cdk?  I've tried creating a listener and it tells me one already exists.  I look through the code that is built and sure enough there is a listener on port 80 automatically generated by adding the application load balancer.

Comment: Same happened to me, the alb creates a listener by default but the ".listener" property is an empty list, so the ".listener_arn" property is None. Is there any way to avoid that it creates a default listener?